# Can we pass an array of objects from one activity to another using seriliazable

Tags: java, android, serialization

this is what i am doing.

"e" is defined as

```
Option e[];
```

where Option is my class that implements Serializable

```
Intent intent =new Intent(this,list_create.class); 
intent.putExtra("element", e);
startActivity(intent);
```

and in the second activity i am retrieving like this

```
Intent i = getIntent();
Option e = (Option)i.getSerializableExtra("element");
```

but its giving a java.io.notSerializableException at "startActivity(intent)". 
What am i doing wrong here??

Comment: May be you can find solution in this link

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4551926/java-io-notserializableexception-while-writing-serializable-object-to-external-s][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4551926/java-io-notserializableexception-while-writing-serializable-object-to-external-s

Comment: i have seen both of them befor but none of them teaches how to send an array of objects.

Answer (score 1):

I am not confirm but, May be this can help,

```
intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("elements", e);
```

from second activity get ,

```
Intent i = getIntent();
Option e = (Option)i.getParcelableArrayListExtra("element");
```

Comment: for this one has to implement a lot of parcelable functions. Thats why i didn't use that.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `ArrayList` as container for `Option`. A Arraylist is `Serializable`. The `List` interface is not `Serializable`.

And even if `Option` is `Serializable`, the attributes of `Option` must be `Serializable`, too. If a attribute should not be transfered it must be flaged with the `transient` key word.

Comment: what do you mean by flagged with transient keyword?

Comment: its giving the same error when i am passing ArrayList of type Option.
What should i do?

Comment: @User_ph flagged: like public static keyword transient is a additional java keyword to prevent serialization of a attribut.

Probably one of your attributes is not Serializable. Maybe there are more information in the stacktrace.

Comment: oh got it.
I should declare my ArrayList as: 
"Transient ArrayList<Option> optionList;"  is that what it is?

Comment: @User_ph No....you don't get it. You should first study what Serialization and transient means. Otherwise you wouldn't fully understand the answer.

Answer (score 0):

i think you have to send array object as a bytes and then you have reconstruct from bytes

check this link

[Java Serializable Object to Byte Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2836646/java-serializable-object-to-byte-array)

Answer (score 0):

`Option` is Serializable but you are sending and array of type `Option` which goes against the concept of serialization.

Instead, you should have in your `Option` class an array which contains all of the options you need to send. Then you put just that one element of type `Option`.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass whatever you want.

Make a new class, throw in it whatever you want,
and make it implement Serializable.

```
public class myClass  implements Serializable{
// Whatever fields
}
```