# AsyncTask android error when closing the program after

Tags: android, android-asynctask, serializable

i am developing an android news reader apps. I have a AsyncTask that implements Serializable, so that i can save instance. I use it to handle the app refresh when rotating my phone. It work, when i rotate my apps, the task still running. but when the task is running, and i press the home button/back button to close my apps, my apps become force closed. Is there anything wrong with my code?

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(final Bundle outState) {
    // super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putInt("curPage", mPager.getCurrentItem());
    outState.putInt("drawerPos", drawerPos);
    outState.putSerializable("task", task);
    if (dialog != null) {
        outState.putBoolean("isDialogShowing", dialog.isShowing());
    } else {
        outState.putBoolean("isDialogShowing", false);
    }
    // outState.putSerializable("dialog", dialog);
}

// dismiss dialog if activity is destroyed
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    if (dialog != null && dialog.isShowing()) {
        dialog.dismiss();
        dialog = null;
    }
    if (task.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING)
        task.cancel(true);
    task = null;
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

MyAsyncTask:

```
public class AsyncTaskRefreshRss extends
    AsyncTask<String, String, ArrayList<BeritaHeader>> implements Serializable{

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 3385729493967673390L;

private OnResponseListener responder;

// MyAlertDialogFragment myDialog;
ProgressDialog dialog;
FragmentManager fm;
Context context;
String type;
String subtype;

public AsyncTaskRefreshRss(Context context, FragmentManager fm,
        String type, String subtype, OnResponseListener listener) {
    this.fm = fm;
    this.context = context;
    this.type = type;
    this.subtype = subtype;
    this.responder = listener;
}

public void setFinishListener(OnResponseListener listener){
    this.responder = listener;
}

public void setDialog(ProgressDialog dialog) {
    this.dialog = dialog;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    dialog.show();
}

@Override
protected ArrayList<BeritaHeader> doInBackground(String... arg0) {
    MyWebService ws = new MyWebService();
    try {
        return ws.GetRSS(type, subtype);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }

}

public interface OnResponseListener {
    public void onSuccess();

    public void onFailure();
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<BeritaHeader> result) {
    if (dialog.isShowing())
        dialog.dismiss();
    if (result != null) {
        NewsDataSource ds = new NewsDataSource(context);
        ds.deleteAllBerita(type, subtype);
        ds.createBerita(result, type, subtype);
        responder.onSuccess();
    } else {
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "Gagal memuat",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.show();
        responder.onFailure();
    }
    // asyncState = DO_NOTHING;
}

public static class MyAlertDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    public boolean isCanceled;

    public static MyAlertDialogFragment newInstance() {
        MyAlertDialogFragment frag = new MyAlertDialogFragment();
        return frag;
    }

    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        dialog.setMessage("Sedang Memuat");
        dialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.setOnCancelListener(new OnCancelListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                isCanceled = true;
            }
        });
        isCanceled = false;
        return dialog;
    }

}
}
```

My logcat:

```
07-19 19:37:00.905: E/AndroidRuntime(29243): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-19 19:37:00.905: E/AndroidRuntime(29243): java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object (name = com.karyadigital.beritaku.berita.AsyncTaskRefreshRss)
07-19 19:37:00.905: E/AndroidRuntime(29243):    at android.os.Parcel.writeSerializable(Parcel.java:1279)
07-19 19:37:00.905: E/AndroidRuntime(29243):    at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1233)
07-19 19:37:00.905: E/AndroidRuntime(29243):    at android.os.Parcel.writeMapInternal(Parcel.java:591)
07-19 19:37:00.905: E/AndroidRuntime(29243):    at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1619)
07-19 19:37:00.905: E/AndroidRuntime(29243):    at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:605)
07-19 19:37:00.905: E/AndroidRuntime(29243):    at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.activityStopped(ActivityManagerNative.java:2247)
07-19 19:37:00.905: E/AndroidRuntime(29243):    at android.app.ActivityThread$StopInfo.run(ActivityThread.java:2915)
07-19 19:37:00.905: E/AndroidRuntime(29243):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
07-19 19:37:00.905: E/AndroidRuntime(29243):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-19 19:37:00.905: E/AndroidRuntime(29243):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-19 19:37:00.905: E/AndroidRuntime(29243):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
07-19 19:37:00.905: E/AndroidRuntime(29243):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-19 19:37:00.905: E/AndroidRuntime(29243):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-19 19:37:00.905: E/AndroidRuntime(29243):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1008)
07-19 19:37:00.905: E/AndroidRuntime(29243):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:775)
07-19 19:37:00.905: E/AndroidRuntime(29243):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-19 19:37:00.905: E/AndroidRuntime(29243): Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: android.app.Application
07-19 19:37:00.905: E/AndroidRuntime(29243):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1364)
07-19 19:37:00.905: E/AndroidRuntime(29243):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1671)
07-19 19:37:00.905: E/AndroidRuntime(29243):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1517)
07-19 19:37:00.905: E/AndroidRuntime(29243):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1481)
07-19 19:37:00.905: E/AndroidRuntime(29243):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeFieldValues(ObjectOutputStream.java:979)
07-19 19:37:00.905: E/AndroidRuntime(29243):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:368)
07-19 19:37:00.905: E/AndroidRuntime(29243):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeHierarchy(ObjectOutputStream.java:1074)
07-19 19:37:00.905: E/AndroidRuntime(29243):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1404)
07-19 19:37:00.905: E/AndroidRuntime(29243):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1671)
07-19 19:37:00.905: E/AndroidRuntime(29243):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1517)
07-19 19:37:00.905: E/AndroidRuntime(29243):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1481)
07-19 19:37:00.905: E/AndroidRuntime(29243):    at android.os.Parcel.writeSerializable(Parcel.java:1274)
07-19 19:37:00.905: E/AndroidRuntime(29243):    ... 15 more
```

Answer (score 2):

You just can't make an `AsyncTask` Serializable and serialize it. Why: you just can't make because the system will try to serialize all its fields and so on for each field's fields. And if a field is not Serializable and not marked with `transient` then you'll get above Exception.

If you want to decouple the `AsyncTask` from the Activity when the Activity is recreated, use the configuration changes with Fragments. Here's [an article that describes how to](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/04/retaining-objects-across-config-changes.html).

Answer (score 0):

This fails due to the Context field in your class. Context objects are not serializable.

"When traversing a graph, an object may be encountered that does not support the Serializable interface. In this case the NotSerializableException will be thrown and will identify the class of the non-serializable object."

You can either remove the Context field entirely, or apply the transient attribute to the Context field so that it is not serialized.

```
public class MyClass implements Serializable 
{
    ...
    public transient Context myContext;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Could you not have shared the SO link? http://stackoverflow.com/a/4552014/2558882